# why cuda program crashes during run and not during debug

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

I am working on Windows, using Visual Studio 2008.
My Cuda program crashes during run i.e. the screen becomes black, and I suppose OS kills the kernel since it takes too long to execute (around 10 secs) due to the watchdog timeout. However, I don't understand why the same program does not crash or why OS doesn't kill when I debug the kernel? The kernel still takes around 10 secs (or longer) to execute during the debug.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue;

In my case, when I was executing my program via the NSight CUDA debugger (Visual Studio 2012), it executed fine. However If I ran it outside of NSight, either using Visual Studios internal debugger, or just separately, a call to `cudaGLMapBufferObject(void** devPtr, GLuint bufObj)` would fail, returning the `cuda_status` enum for Unknown Error and if I didn't exit after that other calls would fail with the same error.

It was caused by me forgetting to pass the 3rd parameter (to define the size of runtime sized shared memory) in a kernel where I was using dynamically sized shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone else.

I had the same problem (but working on VS 2013 and cuda 7.5) and I resolved it when I turned off the Generate GPU Debug Information and the Generate Line Number Information in the CUDA C/C++ -> Device part of the properties.

Answer (score -1):

Typicaly these problems occur when there are race condition problems. Since debug run is slower, bug will not occur, but when debugging is off, instructions are processed in different order and program crashes.

Comment: There is no any race condition in the kernel, since I am testing it with only 1 thread. Running even with 1 thread causes the screen to go black, so I suppose this is not due to the race condition but watchdog timeout.

Comment: I am agree with Josef. You should post your code if possible. Cuda program execution has always shown such behavior in visual studio if you are having race condition, out of bound memory access in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Often, this can happen from debug initializing values to zero, whereas release will not initialize the values. First, I would make sure everything is initialized. Race conditions mentioned by another poster could also potentially happen. You may also want to try disabling optimization in the release build. Occasionally, but not often, the compiler will perform unsafe optimizations that break the code. Keep in mind that usually if you think the compiler is buggy, you are wrong, especially for people without several years of experience.

Comment: What values does the debugger initialise to zero?

Comment: My comment is not specific to CUDA, but in general when programming, initialization vs. no initialization is something to look out for when debug and release are different. I actually just checked and it doesn't seem that NVCC initializes the values to anything in debug. Even if no initialization is given by NVCC, it is possible that release and debug will have different values resident in memory, which will cause nondeterministic behavior. Also, the values copied to the GPU by another compiler (CL or GCC) may have been affected by initialization.

Comment: To answer your question, generally compilers will initialize to zero, but not always, and it may depend on the data type. Also, if you are reading from memory that isn't allocated you may hit fences or special values that the debugger / debug heap has set up like 0xDEADBEEF.